# How to stop parent delete if child present

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use constraints in SQLite.

**Scenario:** Stop parent delete if child is present.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrected: SQLite supports foreign key constraints, but they're off by default. You have to enable them **at run time** with this statement. (That means you can't set this once, and expect it to stick. If you forget to set it just once, you can delete rows from the parent and leave orphans in the child table.)

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Details are at [Enabling Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

SQLite can be compiled with foreign key support entirely disabled. That's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have table A (ID, NAME) and table B (ID, A_ID, NICK_NAME)

When you create table A you'd do

```
create table A (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

create table B (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NICK_NAME TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT A_FK FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A (ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

That should cause an error if you try to delete content from table A that is referenced by column B.

EDIT: as noted in the original poster's comment and my own following it, this apparently does not work. Anyone else shed light on this?

Comment: It should, but in SQLite it doesn't. SQLite accepts foreign key declarations, but it ignores them. You have to implememt logical foreign key constraints with triggers in SQLite.

Comment: Very interesting.  Just tried my own example ... wow ... SQLite 3 indicates it has support for this apparently its not enabled.

Comment: Yes, I found the same thing. Details are in my answer. If you don't enable foreign key support, you can also insert into the child table without any rows in the parent. Which makes sense, in a really twisted way.